# LLBL Gen Pro Layer Exposed by WCF via DTO

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, llblgenpro, llblgen

I want to refactor existing windows application by introducing WCF layer in between UI and BAL.

It is used LLBL Code Gen Pro as ORM tool and it uses SelfServing method to communicate with a database.
I want to introduce WCF layer but cant change LLBL auto generated codes to expose entity classes. I am thinking of using some DTO classes to expose entity classes. In this case, I might use some Entity to DTO and DTO to entity converters or mappers which will be very painful task for me.

Can someone suggest a better approach rather than this? I cant use the method what is suggested by LLBL since I am using selfserving method.

Comment: You can use Automapper to convert DTO to entity and entity to DTO. It'll be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Saadi. Automapper is good to map objects. It resolves one part of my application.But how do i introduce WCF layer since entity classes are  tightly couple  with BAL and DAL and LLBL classes and it uses selfserving.